# Android Populating Table

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I am developing an Android application that requires me to populate an unfixed amount of cells in a table layout.  I'll be drawing from a database and would like to populate the table with an array from a C# class.  How can I generate a table cell for each item in the array?  I am rather unfamiliar with XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Jashi said, use a ListView.  In particular to your situation the

[ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) or the [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) sound like they would give you the output you desire.  There is a guide to using a ListView and how it's adapters work [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to use `ListView` for this purpose.